# Unable to post value on a php file when query is completed

Tags: php, mysql

I am using ajax calling in footer.php file :

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "try.php?action=loginSignup",
            data: "email=" + $("#email").val() + "&password=" + $("#password").val() + "&loginActive=" + $("#loginActive").val(),

            success: function(result) {
                    alert(result);
            }  
        })
```

And in try.php file, I am trying to echo a value of hello when insertion of new row is complete:

```
<?php

        if($_POST['loginActive']=='1'){

            $error="";


            $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '". mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email'])."' LIMIT 1";

            // echo $query;
            $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                $error = "That email address is already taken.";
            }

            if($error!=""){
                echo $error;
            }
            else{

                $query = "INSERT INTO users (`email`, `password`) VALUES ('". mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email'])."', '". mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['password'])."')";

////This is the part where I am facing issues
                if(mysqli_query($link,$query)){
                    echo "hello";
////anything echoed here is not getting alerted by browser, but the query still runs successfully and the new row is being added to my database.

                }
                else{
                    echo "query couldn't be answered";
                }

            }
        }

?>
```

When I run my index.php file which includes footer.php, the page does'nt alerts any value, but the new row is created in my database as per query. I tried everything but could'nt figure out why my "hello" message is not getting alerted by browser when the query is successfully completed. Also, I tried it with a different simple SELECT query and the "hello" message was alerted without any issues. I guess the INSERT query is what's creating a problem here. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: is your data getting inserted in database?

Comment: yes its getting inserted.

Comment: i think you have an extra cruly bracket in the end `}`

Comment: No, I just checked it agian. It's good...it is for the first if condition.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Does all data reach the server as expected? Additionally, please don't use unsecure INSERT queries, prepared statements help you to provide some more security against SQL injection

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cG-F3MU80B_l9H5kPk5BmauB2Xw0d9sj

I have tried my best to get pass this error, but I guess I am stuck here. I would really appreciate if you could have a look on my project files. As of now only footer.php and try.php would require your look according to me. Please help me out with this.

Answer (score -1):

Before calling the ajax function you should get the data, and then send the data to the server with proper format. See if this helps you. ↓↓

```
// get the value from input fields
var email       =  $("#email").val();
var password    =  $("#password").val();
var loginActive = +$("#loginActive").val();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "try.php?action=loginSignup",
    // the correct format to send the data
    data: {'email': email, 'password': password, 'loginActive': loginAcitve},
    success: function(result) {
                 alert(result);
             }  
})
```

Comment: I've already added all the explanation of all the changes that needed to be performed. Please clarify what more information I need to add, I will do so. ::)

Comment: You haven't explained why this makes a difference. According to the question, the `INSERT` query works fine but the output is not done  as expected. As far as I read your answer, you focus on changing the request itself. Or does changing that also modify the output?